# Problem in getting all event in EventLogFile

Tags: eventlogfile

I am not sure what configuration I am missing here, However when I run below query in Developer console in my Developer Org, I get all events like Visualforce, ReporExport, Apex Trigger etc... but when I run same query on my production Organization, I only get Login and Logout files. Production Org is hugely customized and millions of API's are being used daily but I am not getting any log event.

```
Select Id, EventType, LogDate, LogFile, LogFileContentType from EventLogFile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature is a paid one and please contact your AE regrading this.If you are implementing it for the first time,then you have the below options

1. Developer Edition org gets 30 files for 1 day data retention
2. You can get a 30 day trial for all 30 files for their production org: http://sfdc.co/elfTrial
3. You can purchase the add-on

If you saw all the 28 Event log types earlier and if you don't see them anymore then you would have been in limited pilot until and that you were never provisioned a contract for Event Log Files feature.